# How can I pass production role Ids from a custom label into a test method?

Tags: trigger, user

In my test method I'm trying to create users with role Ids from a custom label, but the role Ids are coming back as null. I'm calling a createUser method that takes an Integer(number of users), List, List, String). The class this test method is for checks a user's role against the roles stored in this custom setting.

```
List<User> usersES = TestingUtils.createUsers(4, Label.Profile_Enterprise_Services, Label.Role_ES, 'USD');
```

Am I doing something wrong? Do role Ids persist in test instances? First question and brand new to dev, please be gentle!

Comment: I don't see where are you comparing again the custom setting rol, but take care about custom settings on Test method because they are null and you have to create the values if you want to use them

Comment: In your test class are you creating the records for the custom settings?

Comment: In test method either you have to insert custom setting or apply @isTest(seeAllData=true) annotation.

Comment: I figured it out. I found out you can cast a string as an Id and did this instead. thanks!

List<string> stringRoles = Label.Roles.split(';'); 
Set<string> setRoles = new Set<string>(stringRoles);
List<UserRole> roles = new List<UserRole>();     
   for(String roleId: setRoles)
   {
      roles.add(new UserRole(Id = (Id)roleId));
   }